# How can I install a .egg Python package on Windows (attempt using easy_install not working)

Tags: python, python-2.7, package, qstk

I am trying to install a package named QSTK for a course that I am doing. The course points to an installation package for the 32 bit version, but I have 64 Python installed. I have found a .egg file listed on the [Python packages index](https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/Q/QSTK/).

It seems to have an exe for 32 bit, but just the .egg for 64 bit. I downloaded the QSTK-0.2.6-py2.7.egg version and have been trying to install this unsucessfully so far.

Here is what I have tried:

1. Using easy install (from the C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages
   directory):

   ```
   Python easy_install -Z C:\Users\Prosserc\Downloads\QSTK-0.2.6-py2.7.egg
   ```

   this has created a QSTK-0.2.6-py2.7.egg directory in my
   site-packages directory which I can open and find files in. However,
   I have tried to import QSTK from the python shell and get the usual
   "No module named..." import error.
2. I looked for a setup.py file as I have used these to install
   packages before, but could not find one.
3. I have also looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458311/how-do-i-install-an-egg-file-without-easy-install-in-windows) which gives details of
   installing a .egg file without using easy install, but cannot figure
   out what changes I would need to make to the script provided as this
   is to install a specific package that I already have.

If anyone can help by explaining either how I can install this .egg file correctly or by providing a link to the QSTK modules for python 2.7 64 bit in another format this would be greatly appreciated.

I have managed to install the packages that QSTK is dependant on okay (numpy, scipy, matplotlib, pandas, python-dateutil and scikit-learn).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have finally found another place to download this from with a package that works: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/QSTK/0.2.6 has a QSTK-0.2.6.tar.gz option to build it from the source code.

Unzipping this (then again once down to the .tar), I could find the setup.py file and install by going to the directory with the setup file and running:

```
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 33):

You should add -m before easy_install
for example:

```
python -m easy_install C:\Users\Prosserc\Downloads\QSTK-0.2.6-py2.7.egg
```

Answer (score 13):

How about if you unpack the `.egg` (it's just a `.zip` in disguise), then `cd` into it and run `python setup.py install`? Will that run fine and will you then be able to import your module?

I'm saying this because if the `.egg` file does get put under `site-packages` as appropriate but you're still not able to import, this might be a problem in the code itself.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately, this just gives me the same files that I csan already find in the .egg directory in my site-package, still no setup.py file. I will try an earlier version of the module incase you are right about an error in the code / package.

Comment: Still the same problem unfortunately, easy install seems to run okay and creates .egg dir in site-packages, but install does not work. Checked files on this version as well and no setup.py file included.

Comment: then you have a package problem

Comment: I thought `easy_install` required the existence of a `setup.py`... guess I was wrong then.

Comment: What does it mean if it is in site-packages but I can't import it?

Answer (score 0):

I tried copying the contents of the .egg folder in the path Lib\site-packages .
It worked and didn't throw any ModuleNotFoundError .

Answer (score -1):

I found `pip install qstk` works perfectly for 64x 2.7 python at win 7